# is there any performance issue if we install ubuntu on windows based laptops?

Tags: 14.04

i mean that if we have a windows based laptop then if i install ubuntu on this laptop will it work fine or there will be some performance issue because there are other types of laptop too in the market which are ubuntu based so what is the difference between these two types of laptops.

i wish to install ubuntu on Acer predator helios 300 with i5 processor and 8GB of RAM 128 GB SSD 1TB HDD.

Comment: [Test Ubuntu on your hardware *without* installing](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) to find out. It's easy.

Comment: The ones you are thinking of being Ubuntu based are probably just regular PCs with Ubuntu installed instead of Windows.  The Ubuntu download comes with a full live version(that will be slower than installed) that will let you test if all your computer works.  Can also just search with 'ubuntu on Acer predator helios 300' and see if other people had problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to check first if your machine is certified for Ubuntu. Here you have the list of certified Acer Desktop machines:https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?vendors=Acer

If your machine is not in this list, it does not mean it is impossible but you will need to check the main hardware components' specs to make sure there is support for those. Sometimes, a quick web research to see of someone else succeeded is faster:
[This page suggest several people managed to install Ubuntu on this model](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/540432/linux-install-on-acer-predator-helios-300-g3-571)

Last, if you are trying to create a dual boot. Some PC manufacturers are now freezing their system to avoid that. You need to check first Acer's technical specs to see if their setup is compatible with a UEFI.

Finally if you already have the machine you can also run Ubuntu with a USB Live boot before installing to validate you don't have any error.